# How do you declare a variable for a class whose constructor takes an rvalue?

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11

C++11 introduced the notion of an rvalue argument using the && operator. How do you declare a variable of a class whose constructor takes an rvalue as a parameter? I need to do so because I want to add a member variable to a class that allows me to assign this variable in the constructor and then use it later. My immediate example is [mongocxx::database](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/classmongocxx_1_1database.html), whose (only) constructor is:

```
database (database &&) noexcept;
```

The example in the [MongoDB C++ documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-(New-Driver)) declares and <s>assigns</s> initializes such a variable in a single statement, which works fine:

```
mongocxx::instance inst{};
mongocxx::client conn{};

auto db = conn["mydb"];
```

but that only works if the assignment is done in the same statement as the declaration. How do you do the equivalent of the following?

```
mongocxx::instance inst{};
mongocxx::client conn{};
mongocxx::database db;

db = conn["mydb"];
```

---

Updated to change "assigns" to "initializes" as suggested in the comments.

Comment: According to the documentation, you can't because `database` has no default constructor.

Comment: Well, now a move assignment operator needs to be present. (And a default constructor.)

Comment: There is a move assignment operator for this particular class. How does that help solve the above, though?

Comment: What's the problem though with the first snippet?

Comment: Since the `db` is useless without `conn[str]`  evaluate the connection string first and postpone `db = conn[str]`

Comment: JBL: The problem is that I can't reuse the database object outside the scope where it's initialized, because it has to be declared and initialized in the same scope. I'd like to be able to keep a copy of it in a class member variable, and then use the same database connection in other class methods without reinitializing it every time I use it.

Comment: Is there an issue with just initializing it in your class constructor?

Comment: The initializing would work fine, but it would have to be *declared* as local to the class constructor for that to work, and that would preclude using outside the constructor, which makes it less than useful.

Comment: Why not do it in the initialization list so you don't need a default constructor, or have a factory method if it's too complex for an initialization list.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off. You could always pass rvalues into [some] functions as arguments (e.g. `exit(0)`). What you're doing here is accepting an rvalue _reference_. That's new, and it accounts for the situations not covered by "[some] functions" in my second sentence.

Comment: _"but that only works if the assignment is done in the same statement as the declaration"_ Then it's not an assignment; it's an initialisation.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester I'm one of the authors of libmongocxx. We could add a default constructor to mongocxx::database. If we did so, a default constructed mongocxx::database object would be in a state much like a moved-from database object: valid only for assignment or destruction. Any other operations would be UB, and likely crash. Would a default constructed mongocxx::database object with those semantics still be useful for you?

Comment: That would be tremendous provided that there is a predicate to tell whether it has been initialized (e.g. IsValid()). The use case that precipitated my question is an important one, I think.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester I think an explicit operator bool might do the trick.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester Filed as https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-608

Comment: @ScottDeerwester FYI PR: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/pull/341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both this:

```
struct conn_holder
{
   mongocxx::database db = conn["mydb"];
};
```

or this:

```
struct conn_holder
{
   conn_holder(mongocxx::database&& arg) : db(std::move(arg)) { }
   mongocxx::database db;
};

int main()
{
   conn_holder ch{conn["mydb"]};
}
```

should work.

Keep in mind that `conn_holder` can't be copied, only moved, and it can have a default constructor only if you provide a default value to be moved into the `db` member.

---

An alternative for postponing the initialization in such cases is to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) to store `db`, but then you have to test if the value is there before using it. Some info about using this with data members is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/quick_start/optional_data_members.html).

Comment: You can even do `conn_holder(mongocxx::database arg) : db(std::move(arg)) { }`